# CNF Simplification Algorithm

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, conjunctive-normal-form

Given that a boolean expression is in conjunctive normal form: is there a "simple" algorithm to simplify it while keeping it in CNF?

In particular, what property of the following expression causes this simplifiation?

```
(~a+b+c)(a+~b+c)(a+~c)
```

simplifies to ...

```
(~a+b+c)(a+~b)(a+~c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) of your example is:

[image]

To get a simplified [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF), '1' cells are grouped to get a cover with the minimum number of [minterms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms).

Similarly, one can group the '0' cells to get an inverse cover with the minimum number of terms.

The inverse map:

[image]

The literals of the resulting terms have to be inverted to arrive at the desired minimum [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

> (a + ~b) (a + ~c) (~a + b + c)

The procedure makes use of the fact that the inverse of a [minterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) is a [maxterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) (commonly called [CNF clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)) with inverted literals.